# How to send messages from Mule to ActiveMQ in batches

Tags: java, mule, activemq-classic

In mule I have a flow that receive an InputStream with a 500mb xml file.

I want to split the xml file following certain rules.

The result is 390000 messages that I need to send to an ActiveMQ queue.

ActiveMQ will give an outofmemory exception if I send all messages in one transaction.

If I don't use transaction it will succeed but it will be much slower.

What's the best way to send the messages in batches of 1000?

Can I use standard components?

I am using ActiveMQ 5.13 and Mule 3.7

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for batch commits [doc here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/batch-filters-and-batch-commit#batch-commit-characteristics).
This component will execute the internal flow components once he collected the specified numbers of records.
Example:

```
<batch:commit size="100" doc:name="Batch Commit">
    <!-- Put here all the message processor you want for example the active mq one -->
</batch:commit>
```

Please note that transaction are allowed only at step level and therefore also in the commit block that I think this is exactly what are you looking for.

Footnote: Batch commit processor is allowed only inside a batch step.

Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I should have specified I use the community edtion. Batch commit is available only with the enterprise version.

Comment: A way to simulate this behaviour is to use the mule in memory object store to store your iterations count and trigger another particular flow once you reach the proper count. The object store can be used via java or trough the connector https://github.com/mulesoft/objectstore-connector.
This is the only way as any variable (session,flow,batch) you will try to use inside the batch step will loose is state when moving to next item.
Hope this helps